# How to get data from same txt file in 2 projects in one solution

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, file-io

I am writing solution which consists of three projects. First is class library for both projects, and others are WPF app and WinForms app. This is my college assignment. Both apps need to have access to the same .txt file for storing options. Is there better way than to have absolute path for that file in both projects?

Comment: Hi Gamenood please take a look on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to try to improve your question and since this is a college assignment check [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) regarding "homework" questions.

Answer (score 0):

In your case.You can create a common project.And put the txt in this project and build it as content and you can visit it by path.